# Append a new field to an existing array

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to add the same team name to each entry in the array. A user can currently add multiple names in a single form submission. If a user adds 3 names (first_name, last_name), the data is inserted into the database like this:

```
1. Adam, Smith
2. Jeff, Thomas
3. John, Reynolds
```

I want the user to be able to provide a "Team Name" and then have the team name inserted into each entry in the array, like this:

```
1. The Tigers, Adam, Smith
2. The Tigers, Jeff, Thomas
3. The Tigers, John, Reynolds
```

The same team name is added to each of the rows in the database.

```
<?php

//insert.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing", "root", "");

$query = "
INSERT INTO tbl_sample 
(first_name, last_name) 
VALUES (:first_name, :last_name)
";

for($count = 0; $count<count($_POST['hidden_first_name']); $count++)
{
 $data = array(
  ':first_name' => $_POST['hidden_first_name'][$count],
  ':last_name' => $_POST['hidden_last_name'][$count]
);
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute($data);
}

?>
```

Comment: You will need a special column for it in your SQL table and save it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to alter your table and add a new column to store Team Name. I could see the table name as `tbl_sample` in your question so here below is a query to add a new column: `team_name`

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_sample` ADD `team_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL AFTER `last_name`;
```

**Here is the updated PHP code to support Team Name insertion:**

```
<?php

//insert.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing", "root", "");

$query = "
INSERT INTO tbl_sample 
(first_name, last_name, team_name) 
VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :team_name)
";

for ($count = 0; $count < count($_POST['hidden_first_name']); $count++) {
    $data      = array(
        ':first_name' => $_POST['hidden_first_name'][$count],
        ':last_name' => $_POST['hidden_last_name'][$count],
        ':team_name' => $_POST['hidden_team_name'][$count] // assuming that you have team name also coming in the POST. You can change it to a static value though.
    );
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute($data);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked beautifully. I just needed to remove the the last [$count]...

Comment: @JaredL Please accept it as answer if it helped you :) Thanks